# Temporary variables in C

Tags: c, embedded, microchip

I am using XC32 compiler by Microchip, and it does not allow declaration of variables inside loops (does not support C99), so I can not do this:

```
for(int i = 0;i<10;i++)
    {do w/e}
```

I would hate to make it a global, because it would be hard to keep track of it's value in big projects, using the same thing in various loops, even if you initialize it to `i = 0` in every loop. I even had a bug with this, when it turned out to do weird stuff if you have a few nested loops using the same `i`.

As far as I understand, I can't "undeclare" it manually, but variables defined inside a block of code are undeclared after the pass trough the block? Is this true, and does that mean that this this code will act like the code above:

```
{
     int i;
     for(i = 0;i<10;i++)
        {do w/e}
}//no i anymore?
```

Comment: Yeah you got that right. Just declare the variable inside the scoped block and you should be good. I have no experience with XC32 compiler, but most compilers accept blocks like that.

Comment: Does it support C89 / C90?

Comment: This compiler conforms to the ANS X3.159-1989 Standard for programming languages. 
This is commonly called the C89 Standard.

Btw, to be more specific, it also does support C99 mode but many features I need don't seem to work with it.

Comment: Btw, thanks for the extra effort embedded.kyle, is there a way to give you points on this, I don't see how? :)

Comment: I feel that Microchip are moving on to new technologies far too quick. I would ask them why they are using this 25 years old compiler. They should be using a 40 years old compiler to match their MCU architecture.

Comment: you can develop for that mips processor using stock gnu cross compilers, you do lose the microchip libraries which you would have to replace (maybe you can just port directly, but you get out from under microchips compiler limitations.

Comment: @Lundin I assume that remark is sarcasm? If not, care to elaborate a bit about the subject?

Comment: @cab00t I was very sarcastic. Why people still use this old crap in new projects is completely beyond me. All arguments for using PIC are obsolete. Easy to use? No, get an Arduino with ARM. DIP8? There are Cortex M0 available in that package. Cheap? No on the contrary, it is far more expensive than most MCUs, if you look at amount of flash memory needed to store a certain algorithm.

Comment: @Lundin It was the choice of our electrical engineer, the pic32mx795f512l, for having built in support for lot of things, such as ethernet, uart etc... 80mhz, was good enough for what we are doing. Don't know what could have been a better choice?
I am a rookie programmer, nwe to this embedded field, and am working on my first projecst. I also used Atmel atMega32 for a little while, while learning. 
I see you are very experienced, if you can point me in the right direction with any info / ideas, what to focus on, look for...? Talking about in a broad, general kind of way?

Comment: A quick Google for "arm cortex ethernet" gives hits on TI, ST, NXP, Freescale, Atmel, Toshiba... Pretty much every MCU manufacturer on the market has this. Also, every MCU on the market has got UART. When selecting a MCU for a project, you typically write a spec and then go check how many alternatives there are on the market. What seems unique for the MCU you've picked, is that there's 2 CAN bus controllers. Meaning that it is somewhat specialized for CAN. If you need that plus ethernet, it usually narrows down the alternatives a bit.

Comment: Still, all MCU manufacturers should have at least a few alternatives with 2x CAN, Ethernet and UART. Most likely cheaper than the PIC and certainly much more code effective. What you should ask your EE guy is which alternatives he compared the PIC with. And if he didn't do that but picked the first one he saw, he's incompetent and will cost your company a lot of money. Picking the right MCU is very important. Pick the wrong one and you will bloat costs or force a very expensive porting of the project in the future.

Comment: Considering the number of units is not that big of a deal this time. I certainly see your point though. 
He used PIC in previous projects, that is likely to be the main reason behind this decision. 
What would be your (personal) preferred alternative to [link](http://www.microchip.com/pagehandler/en-us/family/32bit/) ? Something with similar in features? I would like to compare them, maybe try them out?
And what exactly do you mean by "more code effective"? 
Less number of instructions for the same code? A more efficient processor architecture? Less space for the same code? More value?

Comment: Which MCU to pick depends on the nature of the application. Unless you have some very specific requirements, ARM is most likely the best choice. When it comes to ARM, I have no preference, I've only worked with NXP's ARMs and have nothing to compare them with.

Comment: As for code efficiency, "less number of instructions for the same code, a more efficient processor architecture, less space for the same code, more value" are all the same thing and mean the same thing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to C99 standard, the scope of a variable declared in the *clause* statement of the `for` loop is restricted in scope to that loop.

In C89 / C90, that *clause* is merely an optional *expression*.

Therefore in C89 / C90 you can confidently emulate the C99 behaviour with

```
{ /*open scope block*/
   /* your declaration here, including possible definition*/
   for (expression; ...){
   }
} /*close scope block*/
```

Answer (score 3):

By putting it in a block you will indeed be rid of it at the conclusion of the block in question.

What this means exactly, however, depends on the compiler, the architecture, and the environment.

Answer (score 2):

The variable scope is inside the block in which it is defined. So once the block is finished you cannot access the variable.

You may find this helpful:-  [Local variables display as “Out of Scope” when they are most clearly NOT out of scope.](http://www.microchip.com/forums/m697937.aspx)